# dumb down - "to lower the general level of intelligence in"?

Tags: idioms

I looked up an idiom in Merriam-webster.

But I couldn't understand why the sentence ends without anything after a preposition "in".

Doesn't it need "something" after "in"?

[image]

Comment: To dumb down **X**: to lower the general level of intelligence in **X**.

Comment: Look at the first example as well: to lower... content **of** (something, such as a textbook). That also ends with a preposition "of", followed by a parenthetical object, "something". They expect the reader to take that as an example for  "to lower the ...level... in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dumb down [something] means to lower the level of intelligence in [that thing].
The existence of the direct object, and its usage after "in", is implied by the dictionary definition.